# local.xml stops working after upgrade Magento from 1.7.2 - 1.8.0

Tags: magento, upgrade

after upgrade magento from 1.7.2 to 1.8.0 my custom setting in local.xml stops working. Changing file permissions doen’t give any effect. Maybe anyone had the same issue and fix it 
path to file: /var/www/site.com/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/local.xml
Content of my local.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>

<reference name="left">
<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="cart_sidebar">
   </reference>
</default>

<customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
           <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
        </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

</layout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the content is unchanged?  Is your store using the correct package/theme?

Comment: Thanks for reply Steve! I had just copied Magento Modern theme to  folder [mytheme] and in admin panel chose it(and all works pretty good in 1.7.2). I had change theme to modern in admin panel few minutes ago, and local.xml to var/www/site.com/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/local.xml but the same trouble :((

Answer (score 0):

It works in 1.8. Just make sure that your cache is disabled in system / cache management. Then refresh your pages after uploading local.xml to your theme's layout folder. Your changes should render.